# How to add SSL certificate inside Docker container, what should be the location of SSL certificate inside container?

Tags: dockerfile

I want to add SSL certificate to make site secure which is running on Docker container. How can I find out the exact location where I can update SSL certificate? I have tried to update certificate inside /etc/ssl location but it did not work.

Comment: What technologies are you using?

Comment: want to update the certificate inside docker container, i tried to update it in usr/local/share/ca-certificates

Comment: certtificate has been added in that location but still site is showing not secure

Comment: It's incredibly dependent on what software the image is running: a Tomcat image will put it somewhere different from nginx will put it somewhere different from a development server.  There's no universal "in Docker" answer.

Comment: i need to update a tomcat image